# Changing attributes on a UITextView without resetting the attributedText property

Tags: ios, uikit, core-text

I have a `UITextView` that is parsed and has its attributes changed when certain characters are typed. The text is not changed, only the attributes that describe the text's formatting.

If I parse on every character entry, I'm essentially grabbing the `text`, creating an attributed string with the right formatting, and setting the `attributedText` property of the textview to my new attributed string. This totally breaks autocorrect, the double-space shortcut, and spell check.

If I parse only when certain special characters are typed, this works a little better, but I get weird bugs like the second word of every sentence is capitalized.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if (text.length == 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    unichar firstCharacterInText = [text characterAtIndex:0];
    if (/* special character */) {
        [self processTextView];
    }
}

- (void) processTextView {
    NSString *text = self.text;

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontRegular size:12.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor textColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
    // set other properties 
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to change the text attributes of my text view without resetting the textview's `attributedText` property and breaking all those handy features of `UITextView`?

Comment: Just for posterity: I had the same issue with autocorrect breaking when I was setting the attributedText in textViewDidChange/shouldChange and was about to file a radar when I realized this isn't really a bug: this behaivour is caused by the fact that the text view totally changes its contents every time a new character is inputted, so autocorrect, the double-space shortcut, etc. don't get a chance to work. I don't see a solution to this, other than exploring CoreText.

Comment: With iOS 7, you can use `TextKit` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Highlight texts in a range without reseting *attributedText* (NSAttributedString) property of UITextView.

```
let range = NSRange(location: 100, length: 20)
let attribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow]
textStorage.addAttributes(attribute, range: range)
```

***textStorage*** is a property of UITextView.

Comment: amazing only textStorage helped me thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on `fatuhoku`'s comment above. You can call

```
func setAttributes(_ attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]?, range: NSRange)
```

On the text view's `.textStorage`.

Comment: Awesome tip. Should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that setting *attributedText* property of UITextView was triggering *textViewDidChange:* method. So, setting *attributedText* property from inside *textViewDidChange:* method created an infinite loop.

I made a quick fix in which I would immediately return from *textViewDidChange:* method every other time I make a call to that method. It seems to work OK, but I still need to check some more.